# Confusion about the use of the term "Phase Space" in Strogatz text

Tags: soft-question, terminology, phase-space

I've just started learning about Hamiltonian mechanics, and from the definition given in Taylor's classical mechanics, phase space must always have an even dimension. However, I recall from reading Strogatz's *Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos* text, that he seems to use the term differently, allowing [phase space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) to be of any dimension. If anyone is familiar with Strogatz's text, is he using phase space to really mean configuration space? In 1-d, he says that flows on the line constitute 1-d phase space, but the case of 2-d dynamics,the dynamics play out in the $xy$-plane, but since for these systems $y=x'$, this would essentially be the same as the phase space, or at more specifically, state space. I'd appreciate if someone could clear up my confusion.

Comment: I don't have your books (so this may or may not be related), but in physics most ODEs are of 2nd order (F=ma), which means that even for the simplest system you need both position and velocity to describe its state (think initial conditions). Surely you can, in general, have ODEs of 1st order, where only one value is needed to describe the state.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Note that the word _phase space_ is used in various areas of physics outside the Hamiltonian formalism. Different authors use different terminology.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, conventional phase space is even-dimensional, but in Nambu dynamics it can also, in principle, be odd-dimensional, and the peculiar math of Nambu brackets all but dictates embedding odd ones into [larger] even ones.

Strogantz simply generalizes the definition to include all the information of the system needed, so, as he *explicitly says*, he defines an extra variable, $x_{2n+1}\equiv  t$, whose velocity is fixed, =1, and need not be considered or plotted. You might be overthinking it.